# I'd like to add an extra column (variable) to my existing data set as part of an assignment but am unsure how to do it

Tags: r, subset

In R Studio I have a data set of 10 columns and I am required to add a further column (further variable) which is the average of 2 columns already there.

We have been told to use this formula: Tav = (Tmax+Tmin)/2 to create an extra column for the average of tmax and tmin but it does not work for me.
I attach an image showing my situation:

[image]

Comment: See `help("within")` and of course read [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your screenshot, I think this is what you're after:

```
 abp$tav <- (abp$tmax+abp$tmin)/2
```